# GsonBuilder setPrettyPrinting doesn't print pretty

Tags: gson

I'm using the following code ([found on this webpage](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/)) and the Gson library (2.8.2) to format JSON code with pretty printing.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String jsonData = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\",\"age\":35,\"position\":\"Founder\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"java\",\"python\",\"shell\"]}";

      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
      String json = gson.toJson(jsonData);

      System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

This is the expected result:

```
{
  "name": "mkyong",
  "age": 35,
  "position": "Founder",
  "salary": 10000,
  "skills": [
    "java",
    "python",
    "shell"
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately "pretty printing" doesn't work at all and I get everything in one line:

```
{\"name\":\"mkyong\",\"age\":35,\"position\":\"Founder\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"java\",\"python\",\"shell\"]}"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to parse the JSON, and then call `gson.toJson()` on the resulting parsed JSON.

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonData);
String json = gson.toJson(jsonElement);
```

Your current code is just telling GSON to convert some `String` into JSON, and the result of that is the same `String`.

Comment: Yes sir, sure :-)

Comment: My json data is already parsed as a `JsonObject`. but it is still not pretty printing.

Answer (score 8):

nickb made my day! :-)

The correct code must look like this:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

public class GsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonData = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\",\"age\":35,\"position\":\"Founder\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"java\",\"python\",\"shell\"]}";
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonData);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(jsonElement);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
    "name": "mkyong",
    "age": 35,
    "position": "Founder",
    "salary": 10000,
    "skills": [
        "java",
        "python",
        "shell"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i know i'm late. But `JsonParser.parse()` is deprecated from **com.google.code.gson v2.8.6**

instead use the static method `parseString​(String json)`:

```
 public String formatFormat(String source) {
    JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(source);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    return gson.toJson(jsonElement);
 }
```

import statement : `import com.google.gson.*;`

You can also use static methods like `parseReader​(JsonReader reader)` or `parseReader​(java.io.Reader reader)` if your input source type is different from string.